# Are there projects that can used to replace or advance the closed source part of Virtual Box and what are their names?

Tags: virtualbox, open-source

VirtualBox is open source in parts and closed source in parts.

**Sample for Open Source part:**

- VirtualBox manager

The source code can be found on:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20230215155445/https://github.com/mirror/vbox
```

**Sample for closed source part:**

- the extension pack.

**See also the follow from Wikipedia:**

"The core package is, since version 4 in December 2010, free software under GNU General Public License version 2 (GPLv2). The separate „VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox extension pack“ providing support for USB 2.0 and 3.0 devices, Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP), disk encryption, NVMe and Preboot Execution Environment (PXE) boot is under a proprietary license, called Personal Use and Evaluation License (PUEL), which permits use of the software for personal use, educational use, or evaluation, free of charge.[30] Since VirtualBox version 5.1.30[31] Oracle defines personal use as the installation of the software on a single host computer for non-commercial purposes.[32] Unlike some software using a proprietary license, the „VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox extension pack“ is not source-available since it includes closed-source components, which does not make the source code publicly available.

Prior to version 4, there were two different packages of the VirtualBox software. The full package was offered gratis under the PUEL, with licenses for other commercial deployment purchasable from Oracle. A second package called the VirtualBox Open Source Edition (OSE) was released under GPLv2. This removed the same proprietary components not available under GPLv2."

Source:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox

**Are there projects that replace or advance the closed source part of Virtual Box and what are their names ?**

Answer (score 2):

> Are there projects that replace the closed source part of Virtual Box and what are their names?

No.

Answer (score 2):

While no, there are alternatives that are completely open source. If you want something dead simple that just works for running other modern operating systems (eg Windows 8/10/11, macOS, or one of the massive number of Linux distros they support), try [quickemu](https://github.com/quickemu-project/quickemu). In quickemu, you just select an OS, and it will download the ISO, create an optimised VM, and let you boot it easily.

If you want something more powerful, like Virtualbox, use [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/). Although its website is horrible, it is one of the best and most powerful GUI hypervisors for Linux.

Comment: Proxmox are a well know alternate also, but its not asked for.

Answer (score 0):

**Projects using the QEMU code:**

> Many virtualization solutions (VirtualBox, Xen, FAUmachine, Win4BSD, Win4Solaris, Win4Lin) use parts of the source code of QEMU.

Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Weitere_Details

> The Xen virtual machine monitor
> KVM, Kernel-based Virtual Machine for Linux
> VirtualBox, an open source x86 virtualizer.
> SerialICE, a system software debugger
> MARSSx86, a cycle accurate accurate x86 simulator that uses QEMU

Source: https://wiki.qemu.org/Links#Projects_using_the_QEMU_code

**BIOSes and firmware used by QEMU**

> The PC BIOS from the Bochs IA-32 Emulator Project
> The LGPL VGA BIOS projec
> The OpenBIOS project, an open source Open Firmware implementation
> The OpenHackWare (archived 2008-01-24) Open Firmware implementation
> SLOF, the Slimline Open Firmware, is used in QEMU for the "pseries" machine
> Etherboot images from ROM-o-matic
> The EFI BIOS comes from the TianoCore Project.
> OVMF provides UEFI support for IA32 (x86) and X64 (x86-64) guests.
> U-Boot, a firmware which is used for some PowerPC boards in QEMU

Source: https://wiki.qemu.org/Links#BIOSes_and_firmware_used_by_QEMU

**On Github can found some Open source guest add ins for VirtualBox.**

- vboxsf: VirtualBox guest additions for Android
- kos-virtualbox-guest : VirtualBox Guest Additions driver for KolibriOS
- virtualbox-guest-additions-updater: VirtualBox Guest Additions Updater

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20230218013350/https://github.com/topics/virtualbox-guest-additions

**Open Source Alternative to VirtualBox's Graphics Driver:**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230218014357/https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=98613
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230218014504/http://www.os2museum.com/wp/nt-video-miniport-for-virtualbox-with-source-code/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230218014605/https://github.com/Zero3K/boxvnt

Comment: these do not replace the closed-source part of Virtualbox at all. They are alternatives to the whole of Virtualbox.

Answer (score -1):

**It exist at minimum the follow Open Source extension pack for VirtualBox:**

> 2.21. Other Extension Packs
>
> Another extension pack called VNC is available. This extension pack is open source and replaces the previous integration of the VNC remote access protocol. This is experimental code, and is initially available in the Oracle VM VirtualBox source code package only. It is to a large portion code contributed by users, and is not supported in any way by Oracle.
>
> The keyboard handling is severely limited, and only the US keyboard layout works. Other keyboard layouts will have at least some keys which produce the wrong results, often with quite surprising effects, and for layouts which have significant differences to the US keyboard layout it is most likely unusable.
>
> It is possible to install both the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack and VNC, but only one VRDE module can be active at any time. The following command switches to the VNC VRDE module in VNC:
>
> VBoxManage setproperty vrdeextpack VNC
>
> Configuring the remote access works very similarly to VRDP, see Section 1.1, “Remote Display (VRDP Support)”, with some limitations. VNC does not support specifying several port numbers, and the authentication is done differently. VNC can only deal with password authentication, and there is no option to use password hashes. This leaves no other choice than having a clear-text password in the VM configuration, which can be set with the following command:
>
> VBoxManage modifyvm VM-name --vrdeproperty VNCPassword=secret
>
> The user is responsible for keeping this password secret, and it should be removed when a VM configuration is passed to another person, for whatever purpose. Some VNC servers claim to have encrypted passwords in the configuration. This is not true encryption, it is only concealing the passwords, which is only as secure as using clear-text passwords.
>
> The following command switches back to VRDP, if installed:
>
> VBoxManage setproperty vrdeextpack "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack

**Source:**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230213222208/https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/otherextpacks.html